# globalCompositeOperation drawing white over background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, alpha, masking

I am having trouble with globalCompositeOperation in javascript for the html5 canvas.

https:     //jsfiddle.net/6j51kxeh/

I am using "destination-in" do draw a black square in a sprite of a heart, so when the the player is missing that heart, it shows.  It draws the black heart alright, but it draws white over top of everything else.  If you comment out the globalCompositeOperation line you will see it is drawn on top of other things (just a random group of sprites from the same sprite sheet).  Thanks for any help.

I am also having trouble just linking to jsfiddle and I'm done playing with it.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");    

canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;

var scale = 4;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");

draw.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
draw.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
draw.oImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
draw.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

var assetsToLoad = [];
var assetsLoaded = 0;

var sprites = new Image();
sprites.onload = loadHandler;
sprites.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38825680/Site/images/sprites.png";
assetsToLoad.push(sprites);


function loadHandler() {
    assetsLoaded++;
    if(assetsLoaded === assetsToLoad.length) {
        console.log(assetsLoaded + " asset[s] loaded");

        Draw();
    }
};

function Draw() {
    draw.save();
    draw.scale(scale,scale);

    draw.drawImage(sprites,0,64,64,64,0,0,64,64);
    // draw.drawImage(sprites,112,80,16,16,0,0,16,16);
    draw.fillStyle = "black";
    draw.fillRect(0,0,16,16);

    //draw.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";

    draw.drawImage(sprites,96,48,16,16,0,0,16,16);


    draw.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`destination-in` compositing is destructive in the sense that it will erase everything on the canvas except where the new (heart) overlaps any existing non-transparent pixels. So this form of compositing is not likely what you need.

To clarify: You want to draw the heart sprite over another sprite image and then later clear that sprite from the other sprite image that the heart was added to?

If yes, then:

- To add the heart, draw the heart sprite over the other sprite.
- To clear the heart, just redraw the other sprite.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");    

canvas.height = 640;//window.innerHeight;
canvas.width  = 960;//window.innerWidth;

var scale = 4;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");

draw.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
draw.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
draw.oImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
draw.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

var assetsToLoad = [];
var assetsLoaded = 0;

var sprites = new Image();
sprites.onload = loadHandler;

sprites.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38825680/Site/images/sprites.png";
assetsToLoad.push(sprites);


function loadHandler() {
  assetsLoaded++;
  if(assetsLoaded === assetsToLoad.length) {
    console.log(assetsLoaded + " asset[s] loaded");

    draw.scale(scale,scale);
    Draw();
  }
};

function Draw() {
  draw.drawImage(sprites,0,64,64,64,0,0,64,64);
}



function addHeart(x,y){
  draw.fillStyle = "black";
  draw.fillRect(x,y,16,16);
  draw.drawImage(sprites,96,48,16,16,x,y,16,16);
}

function removeHeart(x,y,spriteX,spriteY){
  draw.clearRect(x,y,16,16);
  draw.drawImage(sprites,spriteX,spriteY+64,16,16,x,y,16,16)
}

$('#add').click(function(){
  addHeart(0,0);
});

$('#remove').click(function(){
  removeHeart(0,0,0,0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=add>Add heart</button>
<button id=remove>Remove heart</button>
```

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for.  First, the heart I see here is a heart over a black square.  The heart was supposed to mask the black square so only a black heart appears.  Second, this is taking place in the context of a game with a lot of different sprites being drawn in specific orders.  I pulled it out and just drew a few to see if I could get it to work on its own, to no avail.  But my game is updating many times a second.  I just need to be able to draw the black heart without clearing the rest of the canvas.  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: (1) Create a second in-memory canvas that is the size of 1 tile, (2) draw the red heart on that canvas, (3) set `source-in` compositing, (4) fill the entire canvas with a black rectangle--the heart will become black with everything else transparent, (5) use that canvas as an image source to draw on your main canvas: `ctx.drawImage(memCanvas,x,y)`

Comment: Step 4, where everything else stays transparent, I guess I expected that not to turn everything white while drawing on my main canvas.  I apologize, I am still figuring out the site.  The enter button posted the first comment before I was ready, then I took too long trying to edit.  I didn't mean to be terse or rude.

Comment: No problem here. Welcome to Stackoverflow :-) I'm still not clear what you desire--a black heart and what else...?

Comment: That worked.  I'm not sure if I'm supposed to mark this as answered or not.  All I wanted was to be able to use a sprite as a mask.  It is clear that buffers are required to do this well.  Thank you for your help.